# Save state of EditText in PagerAdapter upon orientation change

Tags: android, orientation-changes, android-pageradapter

I'm struggling to make my application retain text entered into EditText when device orientation is changed. In my activity class I use ViewPager + PagerAdapter (android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<LessonItemI> arrayOfItems;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.pager_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this, arrayOfItems);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
        {
            //my code here
        }
    }
}
```

MyPagerAdapter is:

```
    public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
    {    
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<LessonItemI> arrayOfItems;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemI> flag)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.arrayOfItems = flag;
        }
    //overrided methods here
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        final ItemI currentItem = arrayOfItems.get(position);
        View itemView = null;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

I would try to use `onRestoreInstanceState` and `onSaveInstanceState` methos of MyActivity but I am not sure I can get EditText fields from adapter plus it breaks encapsulation of my adapter. I'm considering `saveState` and `restoreState` methods of PagerAdapter but `saveState` returns Parcelable. Do I have to create object implementing Parcelable to save state? Sounds terrible. Bundle would be much better but it is not allowed in PagerAdapter. Do you guys have any thoughts how to handle this?

Comment: You need the text from edit text field to be retained, and the edittext itself. Why cant you use onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState?

Comment: Because `onSaveInstanceState` is a method of Activity class while I initialize view in MyPagerAdapter. I'm currently trying to handle this via saving values of EditText fields and retaining them via `instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)` method

Comment: You mean to say, you are setting data for edit textfield inside pageradapter.

Comment: No, I mean I inflate layout in MyPagerAdapter class. Question is updated with this code

Comment: It doesn't look to be possible to solve my problem via `instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)` method because I don't know when itemView is changed, i.e. when I have to save current values of EditText.

Comment: As of my understanding and knowledge, onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState should help you in this case. Have you tried out?

Comment: @corsair992 yeah, I saw it. But I don't get it how I return Parcelable object from `saveState()` method. I couldn't find any example of this in documentation

Comment: You can just return a `Bundle` on `saveState()` if you have no custom class that implements `Parcelable` to use as the state.

Comment: @EagleEye But look: everything related to EditText is encapulated inside MyPagerAdapter. How does `onSaveInstanceState()` method knows about EditText and text inside EditText?

Comment: @corsair992 It looks like I really can return Bundle instead of Parcelable. Thank you, good man :) I'll try to implement it this way and let you know when it's ready

Comment: Ok, bloody PagerAdapter doesn't want to work. It uses next sequence of methods: `saveState` -> `restoreState` -> `instantiateItem`. We can try to set text entered previously in `restoreState` but thee thing is that PagerAdapter creates not only current view but also the next view. So, if I declare UI components (ediText) as PagerAdapter class fields then it doesn't know to which editText to write the text

Comment: @olyv: You need to save/restore the state of all the items based on position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use fragments and `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `PagerAdapter`. I use three kind of fragments but the whole number of screens in swipe view is abut 10. So, I use the same fragments with different content. To retain state of fragments when view is swiped I use `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(arrayOfItems.size());`. To retain state of fragment on orientation change overrided method onSaveInstanceState

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)    //when rotated
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString("myKey", "myValueToRetain");
}
```

and in onActivityCreated

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
{
    String myValue = savedInstanceState.getString("myKey"); 
}
```